# Split camel case text with number groups

Tags: java, regex, split, numbers, camelcasing

I have strings containing camel case text and numbers and would like to split it.

E.g. the string `"abcDefGhi345J6"` should be split into

```
["abc", "Def", "Ghi", "345", "J", "6"]
```

My best effort is

```sh
"abcDefGhi345J6".split("(?=\\p{Lu})|(?!\\p{Lu})(?=\\d+)")
```

which gives me

```
["abc", "Def", "Ghi", "3", "4", "5", "J", "6"]
```

---

PS: Dupe marked answers are NOT giving expected output as those are are not Unicode agnostic.

Comment: [`(?<=\P{Lu})(?=\p{Lu})|(?<=\p{L})(?=\d)`](https://regex101.com/r/EihDJ8/1).

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. I'll accept the anser by anubhava because it is shorter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex for splitting:

```sh
(?=\p{Lu})|(?<!\d)(?=\d)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qu7sDF/3)

For Java code:

```sh
String[] arr = string.split("(?=\\p{Lu})|(?<!\\d)(?=\\d)");
```

`(?<!\d)(?=\d)` will find a position that has a digit ahead but there is no digit behind that position.